# Internal Error 500 appear when use apache 2.4 with LDAP Authetication

Tags: apache-2.4, ldap, windows-server-2012-r2, svn, centos7

I have an CentOS 7 server with SVN server configured and I have another windows server 2012R2 with LDAP, that I use for domain controller. I can use *ldapsearch* communicate with windows server.

Well my problem now is that When I try to login into svn server via browser, It comes up a Internal Error (500) no matter what I entered.

here is my ldap configuration in `/etc/httpd/conf.moudules.d/10-subversion.conf`:

```
Alias /svn /var/www
<Location />
DAV svn
SVNParentPath /var/www
AuthType Basic
LDAPReferrals Off
AuthBasicAuthoritative on
AuthBasicProvider ldap
AuthName "SVN Server Login"
AuthLDAPURL ldap://172.20.2.3:389/,dc=syd,dc=domain,dc=com?sAMAccountName?sub?(ObjectClass=*) NONE
AuthLDAPBindDN syd\admin
AuthLDAPBindPassword adminpassword
Require valid-user
</Location>
```

and I've got the error message like:

```
[Thu May 12 09:55:02.382284 2016] [authnz_ldap:info] [pid 9720] [client 172.19.12.2:61673] AH01695: auth_ldap authenticate: user a.b1 authentication failed; URI /repo [ldap_search_ext_s() for user failed][Invalid DN syntax]
```

Any help will be appreciate.
Thanks.

Comment: Not related to LDAP, but I **hate** your first two lines of config

Answer (score 0):

the base in your AuthLDAPURL looks wrong, it has a comma right after the the port/slash:

```
AuthLDAPURL ldap://172.20.2.3:389/,dc=syd,dc=domain,dc=com?sAMAccountName?sub?(ObjectClass=*) NONE
```

Try instead:

```
AuthLDAPURL ldap://172.20.2.3:389/dc=syd,dc=domain,dc=com?sAMAccountName?sub?(ObjectClass=*) NONE
```

But really, just get the config from the [apache documentation](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_authnz_ldap.html#activedirectory)

```
AuthLDAPBindDN apache@example.com
AuthLDAPBindPassword password
AuthLDAPURL ldap://10.0.0.1:3268/?userPrincipalName?sub
```

You can use samaccountname instead of userPrincipalName if prefer that your users login with just ther login name instead of the upn.